# Parse relation between user and installation classes

Tags: android, parse-platform, foreign-key-relationship

I'm developing an application using parse.com, In my installation class i want to hold a user's objectId. I tried this code but "currentuser.set" undefined type.

```
ParseInstallation currentInstall = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
currentInstall.set("User",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
currentInstall.saveInBackground();
```

how can i code this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set objects on the `ParseInstallation` object, you need to use "put", not "set".

And `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` returns the user object, not the objectId.

Answer (score 0):

see the android sdk docs section on 'relations"

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers

you are better off holding a relation to the user which is a pointer to the entire user object . Its more trouble to break the user's OID off of the user object.

with a reference to the user , i think that you can get the OID with just ".objectId"...